# error : Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I get this error:

Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        pickFirst  'META-INF/*'
        exclude 'META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.loader_loader.version'


        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.viewpager_viewpager.version'*/
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.0'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.9'

}
```